# R: installing fpp package

Tags: r

I often have issue installing packages in R. Right now I am trying to install R package fpp for forecasting. But it gives me error of non zero exit status and says fpp not found. This has been very frustrating. 
I am using:RStudio
Version 1.1.383 – © 2009-2017 RStudio, Inc.
R version 3.4.4

Please suggest how to proceed.

Comment: Are you installing from source?

Comment: Also, which operating system are you using? Please read [How to Create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and update your post.

Comment: Please show us a clear error message, maybe a screenshot

Answer (score 0):

A common problem installing packages is that beginning R users forget to include the package name in quotes when using the `install.packages()` function.

```
> install.packages(fpp)
Error in install.packages : object 'fpp' not found
>
```

To correct the error, call the function with the package name in quotes. Note that `fpp` installs a large volume of dependencies.

```
> install.packages("fpp")
also installing the dependencies ‘xts’, ‘TTR’, ‘fracdiff’, ‘zoo’, ‘quadprog’, ‘quantmod’, ‘forecast’, ‘fma’, ‘expsmooth’, ‘lmtest’, ‘tseries’

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.4/xts_0.10-2.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 742460 bytes (725 KB)
downloaded 725 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.4/TTR_0.23-3.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 444850 bytes (434 KB)
downloaded 434 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.4/fracdiff_1.4-2.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 107837 bytes (105 KB)
downloaded 105 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.4/zoo_1.8-1.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 915576 bytes (894 KB)
downloaded 894 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.4/quadprog_1.5-5.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 53278 bytes (52 KB)
downloaded 52 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.4/quantmod_0.4-12.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 487516 bytes (476 KB)
downloaded 476 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.4/forecast_8.2.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 2233397 bytes (2.1 MB)
downloaded 2.1 MB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.4/fma_2.3.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 157153 bytes (153 KB)
downloaded 153 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.4/expsmooth_2.3.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 281014 bytes (274 KB)
downloaded 274 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.4/lmtest_0.9-36.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 290639 bytes (283 KB)
downloaded 283 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.4/tseries_0.10-43.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 327787 bytes (320 KB)
downloaded 320 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.4/fpp_0.5.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 81989 bytes (80 KB)
downloaded 80 KB

package ‘xts’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘TTR’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘fracdiff’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘zoo’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘quadprog’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘quantmod’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘forecast’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘fma’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘expsmooth’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘lmtest’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘tseries’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘fpp’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

The downloaded binary packages are in
    C:\Users\leona\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmp0QpwYd\downloaded_packages
>
```